Is there a way to click a specific point/element in a canvas using javascript
How can I apply a click at a specific position in a canvas? (using coordinates seems the most logical to me, but can't find any way to do it, any other idea is welcomed). Note that I do not have access to the code that creates the canvas.
EDIT: Some clarification, the canvas has multiple elements being drawn that i can't select but need to click them. I could find their coordinates manually and do some calculations, but every time i try to pass a click or mouse event into that position is not being taken as a real mouse click (the button that should be clicked, is not).
I tried using x y coordinates but it doesn't simulate the click, I also asked chat gpt to write me something that listens for a click and simulate it but it didn't work either.

what code have you tried? can you detail an MRE? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

maybe you should show URL in question - so we could see if it uses some framework

@fdomn-m thanks for the shortcut!

You can work this out with the mouse event, just like you probably tried.
Here is an example:

var canvas = document.getElementById('your-canvas-id');

// Change the numbers to your desired coordinates
var x = 100;
var y = 200;

var clickEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
  clientX: x,
  clientY: y,
});

canvas.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);


If that didn't work, there is something wrong with your coordinates, or your canvas id doesn't match.

That didn't work, I modified the first line of the code you gave me because the canvas doesn't have an id or class so I used this:
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'); 
but I don't why it doesn't click, I even used js to get the exact coords.

Have you tried this?
let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
let x = 100 // or whatever
let y = 100 // or whatever
canvas.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousedown', {
  clientX: x,
  clientY: y,
  bubbles: true
}))
canvas.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mouseup', {
  clientX: x,
  clientY: y,
  bubbles: true
}))

